# Using Maven Exec Plugin inside Bash

Tags: java, bash, maven

I'm writing a bash script which will execute some part of a maven project. The script looks like this:

```
CMD="mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=$MAINCLASS -Dexec.args=\"cfg.txt TRAIN\""  
echo "Running $CMD..."

$CMD
```

But this fails every time with the following error:

```
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "TRAIN". You must specify a valid 
lifecycle phase...
```

If I skip the `CMD=...` assignment, and just run the mvn part directly, like this...

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=$MAINCLASS -Dexec.args="cfg.txt TRAIN"
```

...it works just fine.

How can I get maven and the exec plugin to understand that I have two arguments in the `-Dexec.args` section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html) `exec:java` has no `exec.args`? It does have `exec.arguments` which takes a `String[]` which would translate into:

```
CMD="mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=$MAINCLASS -Dexec.arguments=\"cfg.txt\",\"TRAIN\""
```

Comment: This is the right idea. I just edited your answer to remove quotes around the strings in exec.arguments. Apparently it takes the quotes literally?

Comment: Actually, exec:java does have exec.args, and it is not all clear what the difference between exec.arguments and exec.args is.

Answer (score 1):

I've just found that this problem might also be solved by putting quotes around the whole `-Dexec.args` value, like so:

```
CMD="mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=$MAINCLASS \"-Dexec.args=cfg.txt TRAIN\""
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really a bash quoting issue, not Maven issue as such.

To debug it do

```
echo $CMD
```

and then cut and paste the result into your command line. Tinker with quotation till it works

Try

```
CMD="mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=$MAINCLASS -Dexec.args='cfg.txt TRAIN'"
```

for starters

Answer (score 0):

Riffing on @Peter Svensson's answer, I suggest:

```
-Dexec.arguments=$(echo $@ | tr ' ' ',')
```

Where $@ is the standard bash symbol for arguments provided to the bash script, and the tr command is changing the list from space-delimited to comma-delimited